# How to show default laravel error page when error in try block?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 I catch update command in try block, like :

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    $page->NonExistingmethod($this->requestData);
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
}
```

Transaction rollbacked, but how to leave the same laravel error page in dev mode?
any redirect is not what I want to see.

and which decision could be good under production ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `return response(...);`. See [Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#http-exceptions) and you will have a complete guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to display the stack trace view that comes with Laravel.

Then you can throw a custom exception like

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    $page->NonExistingmethod($this->requestData);
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw new MyException($e->getMessage());
}
```

or throwing the exception as it is after the rollback

```php
throw $e;
```

Laravel will display the stack trace in debug mode. If debug mode is off, it will display a 500 error page.

Comment: Thanks! That works under dev. Which decision can be under  production? I am not sure now what I want now, say bets common decision

Comment: You can throw the exception as well. The user will get the normal laravel error page or your custom page, or ajax/axios will receive a 500. Depends on your setup. Catch it in your frontend or display the 500 error page. Whatever you want. I think you should handle this error in the frontend to help the user. Depends highly on how often the error will be thrown.